# Error when running Scala project - class scala.deprecatedInheritance in compiler mirror not found

Tags: scala, goose

Im new to java and Scala.
I have downloaded IntelliJ 13.1 and Im trying to run this project (Goose text extractor) as is: https://github.com/GravityLabs/goose

Im using JDK 1.7.0_67 with these project structure settings:

[image]
When Im trying to run the file TalkToMeGoose.scala Im getting this error:

```
Error:scalac: Error: class scala.deprecatedInheritance in compiler mirror not found. scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: class scala.deprecatedInheritance in compiler mirror not found.

at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)

at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)

at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)

at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)

at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)

at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.requiredClass(Mirrors.scala:108)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.DeprecatedInheritanceAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1101)

at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.DeprecatedInheritanceAttr(Definitions.scala:1101)

at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.hasDeprecatedInheritanceAnnotation(Symbols.scala:842)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$validateParentClass$1(Typers.scala:1675)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.validateParentClasses(Typers.scala:1706)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1864)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1738)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5206)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5256)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5293)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5320)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5267)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5271)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedByValueExpr(Typers.scala:5349)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:2985)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$61.apply(Typers.scala:3089)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$61.apply(Typers.scala:3089)

at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:172)

at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:188)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3089)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:4916)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedMemberDef$1(Typers.scala:5209)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5256)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5293)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5320)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5267)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5271)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5345)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.apply(Analyzer.scala:102)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:410)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:94)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:93)

at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)

at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1177)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$$anon$3.run(Analyzer.scala:93)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1557)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1542)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1537)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1644)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)

at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:28)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:64)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:22)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

couldn't find anything relevant on Google...

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of Scala facet settings (Project Structure -> Facets)?

Comment: I just tried to download Goose and run it from Intellig and I faced no problems. So it should come from your conf. Does your Intellij provide consistent highlighting ?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - attached a screenshot.

Comment: @gzou - no consistent highlighting...

Comment: In the module view of project settings, try to change the scala compiler to `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.0-1`. Indeed Goose seems to attach the scala compiler as a Maven dependency.

Comment: @gzou - I did but then Im getting error : "no scala-library*.jar found" ,and if I change it to Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.0-1 - Im getting error : "no scala-compiler*.jar found"

Comment: sorry, try the `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-compiler-bundle:2.9.0-1` which contains both `scala-library` and `scala-compiler`.

Comment: your compiler library is set to 2.11, whereas all the code is dependent on 2.9.0 -- that's the reason for the errors you're observing.

Comment: @gzou I dont have this in the list. Also when I trying to add new library from maven - search "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler-bundle:2.9.0-1" it doesn't find it.. How can I add it manually?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - please see my comments to "@gzou" - Im getting another error when I do that...

Comment: Yes you can create it manually, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to resume my comments:

The compiler library you should use is : `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-compiler-bundle:2.9.0-1`

I don't know why it haven't been created when you opened the Goose project.

But you can create it yourself:

Open the library settings and spot where your system download the maven libraries by clicking eg on: `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.0-1`.

Then click on `New Project Library`, and add to it both `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.0-1` and `Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.0-1`. The file selector has an option to display hidden directories, which can be useful.

Then go in the `Module` settings and change the Scala compiler to the library you just created. (It may take a few seconds before appearing in the list of libraries).
It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to compile goose with maven on the command line. It requires Scala 2.9.0. Please check the version of Scala compiler used by IDEA 13.1. If there are version differences, you can get such an error. Refer http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-ide-user/143ntm6n3p/switching-scala-library-version-to-match-project

Comment: Im also using 2.9.0 - attached a screenshot.